# CSS pushing container down after button

Tags: css

Ah, yet another CSS issue I'm having.

I'm attempting to use custom buttons, replacing a LinkButton with an image. I have the button working, but now the content below the button is not being pushed down. Have tried various things, but can't seem to find the answer.

Here's a jFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3hm5W/

Basically, the div id = sampleForm (the white form box) should start 5px after the div class = action-buttons. Currently the white box contains the red button.

Comment: Wow, there's a lot going on in that CSS.

Comment: Yea sorry, just copy and pasted the entire projects css file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the contents of your `action-buttons` are being absolutely positioned, which takes them out of the normal flow and makes the container have 0 height. Either get rid of the absolute positioning, or specify a height for your `action-buttons` div.

Comment: simple as that. i had tried to put a relative div around my absolute contents within the action-buttons container, but that didn't seem to work. oh well, i can live with a fixed height for my button containers. cheers

Comment: @Rayden May I ask if there's a reason that your buttons are absolutely positioned?